# PHP substr returns less than expected

Tags: php

I have the following text which is submitted through my WYSIWYG editor.  I am limited to 160 characters.  The first output is perfect, however once I use substr to limit the characters, it actually strips off 20 characters even though the original text was within 160 characters. Can anyone help?

```
$stripsms = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($content));
```

Original Output:

> Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries
>   Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they
>   live in Duden on the coast.

```
substr($stripsms, 0, 160);
```

Final Output:

> Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries
>   Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they
>   live i

Comment: Have you checked the output of `substr($stripsms, 0, 160);` - it seems to give the content I would expect. (i.e. the same as the original string)

Comment: This could be a multibyte character set problem. You need to provide more information. If possible you could use the mb_string extension.

Comment: I have tried the same code in PHP7 and the `substr($stripsms, 0, 160);` output works perfectly. Maybe there are some white spaces. Try `substr( trim($stripsms), 0, 160);`

Comment: Can you please post the contents of `$content` so we can reproduce your results?

Comment: What is `var_dump(strlen($stripsms));`?

Comment: Please add your form.

Comment: I suspect this is a white-space issue.  The spaces are still there, but perhaps you are viewing in a browser, so they are not evident - and hence your string looks truncated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be an encoding problem.

Have you tried replacing:

```
substr($stripsms, 0, 160);
```

by

```
mb_substr($stripsms, 0, 160, 'UTF-8');
```

to see if it works better?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the source is encoded with a multibyte character set. `substr` assumes single bytes to represent a character.

There is an *mb_string* extension, however, it is **not installed by default**. If you can ensure the extension can be installed on the target system, you can use

```
mb_substr($stripsms, 0, 160, mb_detect_encoding($stripsms))
```

There is an alternative using `preg_match` with the `u` flag to enable UTF-8 encoding which is compatible to most multibyte encodings. This is natively provided by all PHP installations.

```
preg_match('~^.{160}~us', $stripsms, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```